# Why my MapState variable in Flink is not persisting previous values?

Tags: java, flink-streaming, stateful

I am implementing a Flink program in Java to handle states using `MapStateDescriptor`. I am basing the implementation on this [source](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/state/KeyedStateStore.html#getMapState-org.apache.flink.api.common.state.MapStateDescriptor-). For some reason, the `MapState` is persisting the previous values and I cannot calculate the average that I want. While I am debugging the `averageTemp` is always empty and I never find any key inside. What am I missing on my implementation?

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.RichMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.MapState;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.MapStateDescriptor;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.functions.KeySelector;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.sense.flink.mqtt.MqttTemperature;
import org.sense.flink.mqtt.TemperatureMqttConsumer;

public class SensorsMultipleReadingMqttEdgentQEP {

    public SensorsMultipleReadingMqttEdgentQEP() throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.IngestionTime);

        DataStream<MqttTemperature> temperatureStream01 = env.addSource(new TemperatureMqttConsumer("topic-edgent-01"));
        DataStream<MqttTemperature> temperatureStream02 = env.addSource(new TemperatureMqttConsumer("topic-edgent-02"));
        DataStream<MqttTemperature> temperatureStream03 = env.addSource(new TemperatureMqttConsumer("topic-edgent-03"));
        DataStream<MqttTemperature> temperatureStreams = temperatureStream01.union(temperatureStream02)
                .union(temperatureStream03);

        DataStream<Tuple2<String, Double>> average = temperatureStreams.keyBy(new TemperatureKeySelector())
                .map(new AverageTempMapper());
        average.print();

        env.execute("SensorsMultipleReadingMqttEdgentQEP");
    }

    public static class TemperatureKeySelector implements KeySelector<MqttTemperature, Integer> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5905504239899133953L;

        @Override
        public Integer getKey(MqttTemperature value) throws Exception {
            return value.getId();
        }
    }

    public static class AverageTempMapper extends RichMapFunction<MqttTemperature, Tuple2<String, Double>> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5489672634096634902L;
        private MapState<String, Double> averageTemp;

        @Override
        public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
            averageTemp = getRuntimeContext()
                    .getMapState(new MapStateDescriptor<>("average-temperature", String.class, Double.class));
        }

        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Double> map(MqttTemperature value) throws Exception {
            String key = "no-room";
            Double temp = value.getTemp();

            if (value.getId().equals(1) || value.getId().equals(2) || value.getId().equals(3)) {
                key = "room-A";
            } else if (value.getId().equals(4) || value.getId().equals(5) || value.getId().equals(6)) {
                key = "room-B";
            } else if (value.getId().equals(7) || value.getId().equals(8) || value.getId().equals(9)) {
                key = "room-C";
            }
            // NEVER ITERATES ON THE averageTemp
            for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry: averageTemp.entries()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());
            }

            System.out.println("value: " + value);
            if (averageTemp.contains(key)) { // NEVER CONTAINS A KEY
                System.out.println("yes: " + key);
                temp = (averageTemp.get(key) + value.getTemp()) / 2;
            } else {
                averageTemp.put(key, temp);
            }
            return Tuple2.of(key, temp);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: ** ok. I misunderstood the problem. The code is saving the previous state on the MapState. I was wrong because I was debugging the code. But the problem that actually I have is that it launches more than 1 thread and it overwrites the value of my map at least three times before starting calculating the average.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The state in your map function is on a **per-key** basis. So when your map function is called, and you get the map state, it will be for whatever id is in the `MqttTemperature` record that is being processed.

Given that you want per-room average temperatures, the way I would handle this is as follows:

1. Change the `TemperatureKeySelector` to return `room-A`, `room-B` or `room-C` based on the id field.
2. In the `AverageTempMapper`, have two `ValueState` variables - one is the sum of the temperatures (a Double), and the other is a count. When your `map()` method is called, if either of these two `ValueState` variables is null, initialize it to 0, and then sum/increment.

Comment: nice. Good approach. I am going to try this one. thanks

Comment: Hi @kkrugler , I did in this way (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54535419/how-to-instantiate-a-mapstatedescriptor-in-fink-to-compute-multiple-averages-str/54537072#54537072). Do you have a better approach?

Comment: You should first `union()` the three streams together, then apply the key extractor and averaging to the single stream. Otherwise each stream will be calculating its own average, which isn't what you want.

Comment: yes. It is a simpler query plan in this way. I was trying to include some complexity on it.